# Converting "Days" from Timedelta object to regular object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to merge the two data frames below on "day", but the time delta object is preventing this. My understanding is that I should be able to then do something like `print(df['day'].days)` and get the actual day without the "days."

df1

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

missing = pd.DataFrame(product(range(1,31), range(1,5)), columns=['date','time_of_day'])
missing = pd.concat([missing.assign(pid=_id) for _id in vec], ignore_index=True)
#pd.DataFrame(product([vec, range(1,31), range(1,5)], names=['pid','day','time_of_day']))

missing.pid = missing.pid.astype(str)
```

df 2

```
from timedelta import date

def random_dates(start, end, n=12):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
random_dates(start, end)

df = pd.DataFrame({'datestamp':random_dates(start, end)})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datestamp']).dt.date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datestamp']).dt.time


df = pd.concat([df.assign(pid=_id) for _id in vec], ignore_index=True)

df['last'] = df\
.sort_values('date')\
.groupby('pid')['date']\
.transform('last')

df['days'] = df['last'] - df['date']
df
df['days'].days #doesn't work
```

merging

```
missing.merge(df, how = 'left', on = ['pid', 'day'])
```

corresponding error
[image]

Comment: Your df2 doesn't work. What is 'data'? where is 'pid'? please provide a working example of your data.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Have updated! Thanks!

Comment: sorry what's the issue? is there an error raised? if so, please provide the full traceback. also, `df['days'].days` shouldn't work - the days Series won't have an attribute `days`...

Comment: Provided the error and traceback.

Comment: what is `vec`?, what do you mean to do by `from timedelta import date`? and instead of `df['days'].days`, did you mean `df['days'].dt.days`?

Comment: Vec would be a vector of participant ids ```vec = data['pid'].unique()```

Answer (score 0):

so this would convert to days as a non-timedelta object:

def get_custom_str_time(x):
return math.floor(x.total_seconds()/(3600*24))

df.insert(
0, 'day', df['days'].apply(get_custom_str_time)
)